# Discord.Net Set bot's nickname

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

The title says it all, I want to set the nickname of my Discord bot. I've tried to Google this but I can't find anything.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Also, what version of Discord.NET are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0.9:

```
var server = discordClient.GetServer(01234567689);
var user = server.GetUser(discordClient.CurrentUser.Id);
await user.Edit(nickname: "The bots new nickname");
```

1.0:

```
var guild = discordClient.GetGuild(0123456789);
var user = guild.GetUser(discordClient.CurrentUser.Id);
await user.ModifyAsync(x => {
    x.Nickname = "The bots new nickname";
});
```